# The construction of the 257gon

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, geometric-constructions

If $\zeta\in\mathbb C$  is a primitive $257$th root of unity, the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta)/\mathbb Q)$ is cyclic of order $256=2^8$, so we know that there is a sequence of $8$ intermediate subfields, each quadratic over the previous one, and this allows us to write down a system of quadratic equations which allows us to give an expression for $\zeta$ in terms of rational operations and square roots starting from rational numbrs (up to the ambiguity implicit in taking square roots) At each step we can use the so called *Gauss periods* to make explicit this construction. I carried this out, with the help of a computer, and got the following polynomials:

[image]

Each of these $f_i$ is the minimal polyomial of an element $x_i$, with coefficients an element of $\mathbb Q(x_1,\dots,x_{i-1})$, and $x_8$ a primitive $257$th root of unity.

The pattern followed by the coefficients of the linear terms is clear, while that of the constant term is rather less evident.

> Can one make sense of these numbers?

For comparison, here are the corresponding polynomials for $17$th roots of unity

[image]

and the more modest ones for $5$th roots

[image]

and the $3$rd ones

[image]

I'm omitting the ones for $65537$.

Comment: See Richelot (1832) [1](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/resolveppn/?PPN=GDZPPN002138573) [2](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/resolveppn/?PPN=GDZPPN002138697) [3](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/resolveppn/?PPN=GDZPPN002138743) [4](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/resolveppn/?PPN=GDZPPN002138832) and [Hermes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Gustav_Hermes) !

Comment: At the end of the first part Richelot writes down the equations (and solves them), but he got them in a much better form that I did, although it seems he is cheating in a way, using other periods instead of just polynomial expressions in the earlier roots.

Comment: One has to admire those guys's tenacity... (For comparison, the Mathematica code I wrote to get the polynomials —simplemindedly, with no serious attempt at optimizing anything— computes the polynomials for 257 in less than 2 seconds (I stopped the computation for 65537 halfway, I'll have to think a bit on how to speed things up to get that one))

Comment: Patience is the gate to joy, quoth Hermes. He must have been a very joyous person! :-)

Comment: Once I was visiting the mathematical library in Goettingen, and mentioned to the librarian that I heard they had stored there the explicit details for the construction of the regular 65,537-gon. She nodded knowingly, went over to a flat pull-out drawer, and produced a 200-page handwritten document with all the details. As I recall, some fellow was given this problem for his PhD thesis, went away ten years, and came back with his solution! I hope he got his degree.

Comment: See the paper by Wayne Bishop cited in Chapter 6 of my manuscript [*A Detailed and Elementary Solution to* $x^{17} = 1$](http://pballew.net/Constructable_17gon.pdf), as well as the 10 other references for the constructing the $257$-gon I give on pp. 46-47.

Comment: For pictures of the suitcase containing the dissertation in göttingen, see http://www.mathematik-olympiaden.de/public/17_257_65537/17_257_65537.html

Comment: @FranzLemmermeyer, thanks! Do you know what the tables appearing in pictures 8 to 4 (counting from the last) are?

Comment: Would you be kind enough to share the Mathematica code you used to compute the polynomials?

Comment: @Adrian , the OP doesn't visit MO regularly any more.

Comment: The link to the suitcase is broken, "Johann Gustav Hermes Göttingen koffer" on google images gives some results.